# Use itemAdd for 2 differents <form> in 2 differents functions - Google Script

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to improve some stuff in a Spreadsheet and for that, I need to use html file (index1.html) to take informations from the user in a *form*. All the info are used in my gs file (file.gs) with `function itemAdd(form)`.

Everything is working but then I try to make a new *form* for another problem in another html file (index2.html). Using the same technique, all the info are used in `function itemAdd(form)` and here is the problem.

The gs file can't differentiate the 2 itemAdd when I want to use the first html file or the second... that's normal because I have 2 functions with the same name (`itemAdd(form)`), my problem is how to do 2 different functions knowing that I can't change `itemAdd` and form name! I tried to split into 2 different gs files but I read that Google is compiling all the gs file into one so that was not working. I also try to change the *form* with *form2* for index 2 but not working... I guess the solution is somewhere in the html file and it's over my skills in html.

To try to make you understand as much as I can, here is a simplify example of my problem :

**Code.gs**

```
function onOpen(e) {
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
       .createMenu('Form 1')
       .addItem('Get info 1', 'test1')
       .addToUi();
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi()    
       .createMenu('Form 2')
       .addItem('Get info 2', 'test2')
       .addToUi();
 }

function test1() {  
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index1.html')
.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
       .showModalDialog(html, 'Give the infos);
  }
}

function itemAdd(form) {
    //all the things I want to do with the infos given 
    with the form in index 1
    }

function test2() {  
      var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index2.html')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
           .showModalDialog(html, 'Give the infos);
      }
    }

function itemAdd(form) {
    //all the things I want to do with the infos given 
    with the form in index 2
    }
```

**index1.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top" >
  </head>
  <form>
    Info 1 :
    <input type="text" name="i1">
    <br><br>
    Info 2 :
    <input type="text" name="i2">
    <br>
     <input type="button" value="Ajouter"
        onclick="google.script.run
            .withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close)
            .itemAdd(this.parentNode)" />
    </form>
</html>
```

**index2.html**

```
<html>
      <head>
        <base target="_top" >
      </head>
      <form>
        Info 3 :
        <input type="text" name="i3">
        <br><br>
        Info 4 :
        <input type="text" name="i4">
        <br>
         <input type="button" value="Ajouter"
            onclick="google.script.run
                .withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close)
                .itemAdd(this.parentNode)" />
        </form>
</html>
```

Comment: Why can you not change the function name? You can pass different arguments to the function and decide which function to run.

Comment: ...yes, that work ! It was pretty obvious, sorry :D I don't know why I was trying to change the form name and not the function name ! I thought itemAdd was like a library or something you can't change (I'm a real noob in html)...anyway thanks a lot !