# onClick on Google Script not working for HTML Form

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a html pop up that will then populate a gsheet. I've basically used the same solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34325826/how-can-i-add-multiple-inputs-from-an-html-ui-to-a-google-spreadsheet). For some strange reason though, it isn't working. When I click the submit button on the HTML pop up box after filling out all the data, it doesn't respond. I click, it doesn't close, append the data, or do anything.

The html pop up is created, but the Submit button doesn't work. I am almost sure that it is has something to do with the onClick method I am using.

Here is the code I am working with:

### gs file

```
function registerCustomer() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('customerMenu.html').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
       .showModalDialog(html, 'Add Customer');
}

function customerAdd(customerForm) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet;
  var cus_db = ss.getSheetByName("customer_db");

  cus_db.appendRow(["  ", customerForm.name_1, customerForm.name_2, customerForm.phone, customerForm.age, customerForm.channel]);
  return true;
}
```

### html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  </head>
  <br>
  <customerForm>
    First Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="name_1">
    <br>
    Second Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="name_2">
    <br>
    Phone Number:<br>
    <input type="text" name="phone">
    <br>
    Age:<br>
    <input type="number" name="age">
    <br>
    How did they hear about us?:<br>
    <input type="text" name="channel">
    <br><br>
     <input type="submit" value="Add Customer" class ="submit" 
           onclick="google.script.run
           .withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close)
           .customerAdd(this.parentNode)" />
    </customerForm>
</html>
```

I've scoured stackoverflow for almost every solution:

1. I am running two pop ups so I changed the function names based on the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49174206/use-itemadd-for-2-differents-form-in-2-differents-functions-google-script)
2. I tried to use the '''document.forms[0]''' method found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525553/get-value-of-html-text-box-in-apps-script-function) also didn't work

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean by *Submit button doesn't work*?

Comment: There's no tag called `<customerForm>`

Comment: @TheMaster where is the tag supposed to be?

Comment: It summed be <form> not <customerForm>... not sure where you got that

Comment: changed it, but still doesn't work.

Comment: Could you explain all the **didn't/doesn't work** in your question? See [mcve]

Comment: I've edited the question to include the didn't work: basically the button is supposed to trigger an action, either append or close. It doesn't do anything and the box just stays there un-moved by my clicking :(

Comment: Ok, what about the browser console? It'll show logs

Comment: @TheMaster could you explain a bit more? do you mean adding in a line for browser console to check the logs?

Comment: When you click submit, browser will throw a error in the console. You can access the  console in your browser through menu>web dev tools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**onClick on Google Script working for HTML Form**

GS:

```
function registerCustomer() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ah2')
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(html, 'Add Customer');
}

function customerAdd(obj) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet15');
  sh.appendRow(["", obj.name_1, obj.name_2, obj.phone, obj.age, obj.channel]);
  return true;
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <form>
    First Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="name_1" />
    <br>
    Second Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="name_2"/>
    <br>
    Phone Number:<br>
    <input type="text" name="phone"/>
    <br>
    Age:<br>
    <input type="number" name="age"/>
    <br>
    How did they hear about us?:<br>
    <input type="text" name="channel"/>
    <br><br>
     <input type="button" value="Add Customer" onClick="addCust(this.parentNode);" />
    </form>
    <script>
      function addCust(obj) {
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(function(){google.script.host.close();})
        .customerAdd(obj);
      }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the speedy response. Still not working. The response is a dud. I am now suspecting there is a settings issue at this rate. Your code is doing exactly the same thing as mine was.

Comment: Did you get the HTML file name correct and I think I’m using a sheet name rather than active shee

Comment: Also this is not a templates file

Comment: Yes I am using the correct file name, but let me check again. I don't understand though what you mean by templates file, could you explain a bit more?

Comment: I've accepted and upvoted your answer because it works. Please note though it does not work in the new App Script runtime powered by Chrome V8, which seemed to be the problem. As soon as I disabled it, the script ran.

Comment: Well I believe I saw an evaluate in your HtmlService command.  But perhaps I was wrong.  But you do have `google.script.host.close` and should be `google.script.host.close();`

Comment: In looking at your code it looked to me like you were running the old version.  Perhaps that's some we should all add to our questions these days.

Comment: I just tested it with the new runtime and in the new editor and it works just fine so who ever is having a problem I suspect you are doing something wrong.  Like maybe you hmtl file name or your sheet name  is incorrectt

Comment: Maybe they've made them backward compatible now.