# Google script, html user form, getting data from html user form

Tags: html, forms, google-apps-script

I want to get a text from a html form but I didn't find out how to recover the data. This worked fine in an older version of the form, and also when I reprogrammmed it due to deprecation of UI methods). But now it does not function anymore. I reprogrammed it and the resulting code shows the html form but I can't recover the data.
When I click OK form does not react (when I click Exit, form closes).

Mi code is

**Code GS**

```
var authorName=''; 
    
function onOpen() {
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      ui.createMenu('IM@ICHOS Menu')
          .addItem('Identifiy User', 'showDialog')
          .addSeparator()
          .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Verification')
              .addItem('Show User', 'showUser'))
          .addToUi();
    }
function showDialog() {
      try {
             var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
             html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('InputAuthor');
             SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
                .showModalDialog(html, 'Input author name');
            ss.toast('Author ->'+authorName);
          } 
      catch (event) {
               Browser.msgBox("Error report of [Monitored dialogues]/showDialog: " + event.message);
          }
    }

    //getValuesFromForm
function getValuesFromForm(form){
      try {
        authorName = form.authorName;
        return;
    } 
        catch (event) {
        Browser.msgBox("Error report of [Software and Data Status]/getValuesFromForm: " + event.message);
      }
    }
```

**InputAuthor.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <b>Identifies Author</b><br /><br />
    Please, input your eMail(without domain) to allow proper identification of changes authorship.<br />(message from ICHOS/IM Team)<br />
    <br />

      <b>Input User</b>: <input id="authorName" name="authorName" type="text" />
      <input onclick="formSubmit()"                       type="button" value="OK"   />
      <input onclick="google.script.host.close()"         type="button" value="Exit" />
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      function formSubmit() {
      google.script.run
          .getValuesFromForm(document.getElementById('InputAuthor'));
          .withFailureHandler(myFailureFunction)
          .withSuccessHandler(mySuccessFunction)
      }
      
      function mySuccessFunction() {
      alert("Done!");
      google.script.host.close();
    }

      function myFailureFunction(argError) {
      alert("There was an error: " + argError.message);
      google.script.host.close();
    }


    function getValuesFromForm(form){
      try {
        authorName = form.authorName;
        return;
    } 
      catch (event) {
        Browser.msgBox("Error report of [Software and Data Status]/getValuesFromForm: " + event.message);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your html to something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input name="authorName" type="text" />
      <input onclick="formSubmit(this parentNode);" type="button" value="OK"   />
      <input onclick="google.script.host.close();" type="button" value="Exit" /><!--this only works for dialogs not webapps -->
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      function formSubmit(obj) {
      google.script.run
          .getValuesFromForm(obj));
          .withFailureHandler(myFailureFunction)
          .withSuccessHandler(mySuccessFunction)
      }
  </body>
</html>
```

Then your gs starts like this:

```
function getValuesFromForm(values) {
  const authorname=values.authorName;
}
```

[Here's another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60364126/onclick-on-google-script-not-working-for-html-form/60365261#60365261)

Comment: Thank you for your prompt replying. I made suggested changes but it didn´t work. During the process I found that

<input onclick="formsubmit(this.parentNode)"                  type="button" value="OK"   />

is not working. It doesn't matter what I write inside the function, it is not executed.